# Check if request is encrypted (https) in node 13

Tags: node.js, https, nodes

Node 13 has deprecated the use of request.connection.

It is no longer possible to do `request.connection.encrypted ? 'https' : 'http'`

How can you check if the request is made over https or http in Node 13 ?

Comment: Solution is to use request.socket.encrypted

Answer (score 0):

When server is started with http**s**.createServer the request.socket.encrypted is true.

When server is started with http.createServer the request.socket.encrypted is undefined.

Here's the [docs for tlsSocket.encrypted](https://devdocs.io/node/tls#tls_tlssocket_encrypted)

Comment: This doesn't work if you are behind a reverse proxy. The client will connect to the reverse proxy via https then the reverse proxy will redirect internally to the non secure http server. If you are behind a reverse proxy you need to check the x-forwarded-proto header, otherwise check request.socket.encrypted like you've said.

Answer (score -1):

Try This,

`req.secure` is a shorthand for `req.protocol === 'https'` should be what you looking for.

If you run your app behind a proxy, enable 'trust proxy' so `req.protocol` reflects the protocol that's been used to communicate between client and proxy.

```
app.enable('trust proxy');
```

or you can use,

```
  req.headers['x-forwarded-proto']
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The question is about Node.js so no window available.

Comment: Thanks you for trying but those solutions are Express.js specific and my question wasn't about express but simply raw node request object.
The req.headers solution only work if the request was set with such header.